# OOP not being initiated into variable for later object access

Tags: php, pdo

I have a feeling this is a stupid mistake but its had me stalled for the last 24 hours; I have a class that works perfectly on every other page I use it on. I am now using a very very small version of this class while creating a IPN listener for PayPal subscriptions.

The problem I'm having is that after creating a new instance of the class in a variable (the exact same way i do on all my other pages), and then try to access it, I receive an error saying I'm trying to use a non object variable as an object.

**The condensed version;**

*Creating a new instance of the class:*

```
$Utilities = new Utilitys(new db("mysql:host=XCensored;dbname=XCensored", "XCensored", "XCensored"));
```

*Using the object*

```
$a = $Utilities->db->run("SELECT * FROM XCensored WHERE XCensored =:id", array(':id' => (int)trim($XCensored)));
```

*error log message*

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: Utilities in XX/XX/XX/XX.php 

PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in XX/XX/XX/XX.php 

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function run() on a non-object in XX/XX/XX/XX.php
```

Comment: The notice says exactly where the problem is; of course, you have conveniently left that information out of the question.

Comment: @Jack what have I left-out? the error messages? They're in the question.

Comment: The error messages have line numbers at which the error occurred, but you didn't specify those in your code; there were multiple points in the code where the same statement was used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you're using 'Utilities' and 'Utilitys' interchangeably... unless that's just a typo in your question?

EDIT: Actually, no, ignore me.  I didn't read it properly.

EDIT:  What have you tried to debug this?  I would put few var_dump() statements in different places of the db and Utilitys classes to try and narrow down where things go awry.  Maybe also instantiate the db class in a variable and pass that variable to 'new Utilitys()'.  Check that the db variable holds an object of db first.  If it does, then your problem is inside the Utilitys class.

EDIT: OK, so if you have tried the following, correct? :

$db = new db("mysql:host=XCensored;dbname=XCensored", "XCensored", "XCensored");
$utilities = new Utilitys($db);

var_dump($db);  // do you actually have a db object in $db
var_dump($utilities)  // what comes out here

SOLVED BY ORIGINAL POSTER: "...I figured it out now, and it was a silly error; it was to do with the variable scope, i had to use PHP's global command to get it to work"

Comment: the thing is this is how I create a new instance on all other pages and it works perfectly, so why would it be different here? I have now tested the db class without the utilities and that works perfectly.

Comment: Well you said you in your original question "I am now using a very very small version of this class" which suggests that you've changed something in it.  You didn't post your class, so I can't tell what might be wrong with it.  You are getting an instance of db, so the problem lies in your Utilitys class.

Comment: I don't understand why my answer has been down-voted...

Comment: OK, I want to help you solve this.  I just scrolled down and found your Utilitys class.  First thing that jumps out at me is that you are using $CapitalisedVarNames and $lowerCapsVarNames interchangeably.  You need to stick to $lowerCase as, if you later slip and do $LowerCase, it's not the same variable.  In your original question, you don't say what lines the error occur on - please include this or, better still, put comments in the long code example so we can see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Originally I moved to a very small version of the class after discovering it does not work.
I’ve now removed this class from my code completely, and am now simply using the PDO wrapper class on it’s own, as I said before, the PDO class produced an object and worked running a statement. 
However now I try it further down the page and the same 'non-object' error comes up again. Thanks for deciding to help me! I have no idea why your question has been down voted :(

Comment: The fatal error occurs after the notices (as shown in my original question), so the line where it goes wrong is the first time the PDO wrapper is called; `$a = $Utilities->db->run("SELECT * FROM XCensored WHERE XCensored =:id", array(':id' => (int)trim($XCensored)));`

Comment: Yep I've done that, but Ive figured it out now, and it was a silly error; it was to do with the variable scope, i had to use PHP's `global` command to get it to work. - if you update your answer to include the `global` answer I'll accept yours so others can benefit from it

Answer (score -1):

As Tocacar states, check if the db class is returning an object. Your code seems to be correct.

Assumption is you have problems connecting to the database. If that does not work, you will not receive an object.

As a side note, I find you db class very confusing. The public $dbh variable makes reading your code very complex. Within the db class, you can do parent::execute() etc.

From outside the db class, assume you have an object mDb, you can just do $mDb->execute()

I spent quite some time trying to understand what you were doing. This makes debugging much harder.

And as Tocacar correctly mentioned, avoid using those subtile differences like Utilities and Utilitys, that is just asking for problems later on.